# Query order results according to search results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a search function and take an input parameter and query my database using the following query:

```
select * from people where title like '{param}%' or title like '%{param}%';
```

my question is that this returns all the records as they are meant to but I want to order the results so that the results of the where statement 'title like '{param}%'' return first then the following where statement.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that :

```
  select * from people where title like '{param}%' or title like '%{param}%'
  ORDER BY CASE when title like '{param}%' then 0
                when title like '%{param}%' then 1 end asc
```

Comment: I think you have to use `ASC` as per uesr requirements

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select *
from people
where title like '{param}%' or title like '%{param}%'
order by (title like '{param}%') + (title like '%{param}%') desc;
```

MySQL treats boolean results as integers so you can add them together.  Clearly, if something starts with `{param}`, then it also contains it, so those will have a value of `2`.